# Nearest neighbours with Python

Tags: python, geopandas, nearest-neighbor, distance-matrix, scikit-learn

I'm learning Python and this has been a bit of a challenge!

My DataFrame looks like this below.

```
             name                   geometry
0     Uimastadion  POINT (24.93045 60.18882)
1  Hartwall Arena  POINT (24.92918 60.20570)
2           Talli  POINT (24.92607 60.21346)
```

I would like to create some sort of function on Python that takes an input (an address or name of a single point) then returns the nearest (say 10 0r 100) neighbors including their distances.

I've found this below but its not what I'm looking for.

https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html

How can I do this?

Comment: What about your reference isn't what your looking for?  Did you see that `get_nearest` accepts a parameter for the number of nearest neighbors?

Comment: That function doesn't seem to work on its own. it returns this error. (_float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point'_) . Also, the first part about taking in a value for input. Is this something possible

Comment: I think you are probably having some problems using Python.  Could you edit your post to show some minimal examples with the issues you are having?